# Matlab Solid Circles

Tags: matlab, geometry

What we want is to draw several solid circles at random locations, with random gray scale colors, on a dark gray background. How can we do this? Also, if the circles overlap, we need them to change color in the overlapping part.

Since this is an assignment for school, we are not looking for ready-made answers, but for a guide which tools to use in MATLAB!

Comment: radius would be constant across those circles?

Comment: @Divakar: I assumed no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a checklist of things I would investigate if you want to do this properly:

- Figure out how to draw circles in MATLAB.  Because you don't have the Image Processing Toolbox (see comments), you will probably have to make a function yourself.  I'll give you some starter code:

  ```
   function [xout, yout] = circle(x,y,r,rows,cols)
   [X,Y] = meshgrid(x-r:x+r, y-r:y+r);
   ind = find(X.^2 + Y.^2 <= r^2 & X >= 1 & X <= cols & Y >= 1 & Y <= rows);     
   xout = X(ind);
   yout = Y(ind);
   end
  ```

  What the above function does is that it takes in an `(x,y)` co-ordinate as well as the radius of
  the circle.  You also will need to specify how many rows and how many columns you want in your image.  The reason why is because this function will prevent giving you co-ordinates that are out of bounds in the image that you can't draw.  The final output of this will give you co-ordinates of all values **inside and along the boundary of** the circle.  These co-ordinates will already be in integer so there's no need for any rounding and such things.  In addition, these will **perfectly** fit when you're assigning these co-ordinates to locations in your image.  One caveat to note is that the co-ordinates assume an *inverted Cartesian*.  This means that the top left corner is the origin `(0,0)`.  `x` values increase from left to right, and `y` values increase from top to bottom.  You'll need to keep this convention in mind when drawing circles in your image.
- Take a look at the `rand` class of functions.  `rand` will generate random values for you and so you can use these to generate a random set of co-ordinates - each of these co-ordinates can thus serve as your centre.  In addition, you can use this class of functions to help you figure out how big you want your circles and also what shade of gray you want your circles to be.
- Take a look at set operations (logical AND, logical OR) etc.  You can use a logical AND to find any circles that are intersecting with each other.  When you find these areas, you can fill each of these areas with a different shade of gray.  Again, the `rand` functions will also be of use here.

As such, here is a (possible) algorithm to help you do this:

1. Take a matrix of whatever size you want, and initialize all of the elements to dark gray.  Perhaps an intensity of 32 may work.
2. Generate a random set of `(x,y)` co-ordinates, a random set of radii and a random set of intensity values for each circle.
3. For each pair of circles, check to see if there are any co-ordinates that intersect with each other. If there are such co-ordinates, generate a random shade of gray and fill in these co-ordinates with this new shade of gray.  A possible way to do this would be to take each set of co-ordinates of the two circles and draw them on separate temporary images.  You would then use the logical AND operator to find where the circles intersect.
4. Now that you have your circles, you can plot them all.  Take a look at how `plot` works with plotting matrices.  That way you don't have to loop through all of the circles as it'll be inefficient.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much! This is a very clear plan of action. One problem we have still is how to convert the xp and yp values (which are not integers) to locations in the original matrix.

Comment: @Boreq: I have edited my post to get rid of this problem for you :)  Good luck!

Comment: @Boreq Let me ask you again, do you happen to know if you have MATLAB Image Processing toolbox?

Comment: @Divakar: I sure hope so... because this would be a hell of a lot easier if they did.

Comment: @rayryeng Exactly and neat! Oh well,school you know, full of restrictions :)

Comment: Thanks, this should help us get started! Thank you!

Comment: @Boreq: Found a small bug in my circle code.  Check it out when you have time.  BTW, you're welcome!

Comment: @Divakar: for some reason the image processing toolbox was not installed. Thanks everyone for the tips here! I solved it eventually using a built-in function called 'circle', which created a matrix filled with ones in a circle shape.

Comment: @Boreq Wow! What's that magical `circle` function? Where did you find that one? Doesn't appear to be one of the built-in ones.

Comment: @Boreq: I searched the documentation as well and I couldn't find `circle` either.

Answer (score 2):

Let's get you home, shall we? Now this stays away from the Image Processing Toolbox functions, so hopefully these must work for you too.

**Code**

```
%%// Paramters
numc = 5;
graph_size = [300 300];
max_r = 100;

r_arr = randperm(max_r/2,numc)+max_r/2
cpts = [randperm(graph_size(1)-max_r,numc)' randperm(graph_size(2)-max_r,numc)']
color1 = randperm(155,numc)+100

prev = zeros(graph_size(1),graph_size(2));
for k = 1:numc
    r = r_arr(k);
    curr = zeros(graph_size(1),graph_size(2));
    curr(cpts(k,1):cpts(k,1)+r-1,cpts(k,2):cpts(k,2)+r-1)= color1(k)*imcircle(r);

    common_blob = prev & curr;
    curr = prev + curr;
    curr(common_blob) = min(color1(1),color1(2))-50;
    prev = curr;
end
figure,imagesc(curr), colormap gray

%// Please note that the code uses a MATLAB file-exchange tool called
%// imcircle, which is available at -
%// http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/128-imcircle
```

**Screenshot of a sample run**

[image]

Comment: +1.  I'd totally give you a bounty too!... but let me get to 2k first :)

Answer (score 1):

As you said that your problem is an assignment for school I will therefore not tell you exactly how to do it but what you should look at.

you should be familiar how 2d arrays (matrices) work and how to plot them using image/imagesc/imshow ;

you should look at the strel function ;

you should look at the rand/randn function;

such concepts should be enough for the assignment.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! However, the computers at school do not recognize the 'strel' function. My laptop does, but we have to be able to complete it on the school pc. Any other idea?

Comment: If you don't have `strel`, that means you don't have the Image Processing toolbox... which will make this problem much harder.  I'll write an answer for y'all to mull over though.  Give me about 10 minutes.

Comment: it should be fine without it. just think of a way to define a circle and that should remove the dependency of strel. as an example a 3x3 square can be defined as [1,1,1;1,1,1;1,1,1]